# $T$ is a linear function satisfying $T(AB)=T(BA)$, show that $T=\lambda\cdot\text{tr}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M_n(\mathbb C)$ be a linear space over $\mathbb C$ consisting of all $n\times n$ matrices. Let $T:\,M_n(\mathbb C)\to\mathbb C$ be a linear function satisfying
>   $$
> T(AB)=T(BA).
> $$
>   Show that there exists a $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ such that for all $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$, $T(A)=\lambda\cdot \text{tr}(A)$.

It is very natural for $T$ to have this property. But how to prove explicitly? How to prove $T(E_{ij})=c\delta_{ij}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix which has everywhere zeroes except at the position $(i,j)$, where it has one, and assume that $T(E_{ij})=t_{ij}$. Note that $E_{ij}E_{jk}=E_{ik}$ and 
$E_{ij}E_{\ell k}=0$, if $j\ne\ell$. Hence, for all $i,j$
$$
t_{ii}=T(E_{ii})=T(E_{ij}E_{ji})=T(E_{ji}E_{ij})=T(E_{jj})=t_{jj}=:t
$$
and if $i\ne j$,
$$
t_{ij}=T(E_{ij})=T(E_{ij}E_{jj})=T(E_{jj}E_{ij})=T(0)=0.
$$
So if $A=(a_{ij})$, then
$$
T(A)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}T(E_{ij})=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}T(E_{ii})=\Big(\sum a_{ii}\Big)t=t\cdot \mathrm{Tr}(A)
$$